# Could not find gradle 3.1

Tags: android, gradle

The latest version of gradle is 3.1 [enter link description here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/release-notes)

but Android Studio is only using 2.2?

[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle)

This seems likes a huge discrepancy. My configuration:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2'
        classpath 'de.felixschulze.gradle:gradle-hockeyapp-plugin:3.2'
        classpath 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

When I try to find gradle 3.1, I get an error that it cannot find it. Same now with 2.2    > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.

But gradle -v shows

```
gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.2
```

how do I resolve this?

Comment: I Think you're getting confused with the Android Gradle plugin, and the Gradle Wrapper (`gradle-wrapper.properties` file - `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.1-all.zip`) - https://services.gradle.org/distributions/ Also this line : `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2'` should be : `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'` - from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0/

Comment: Yes, thank you. I am trying that 2.2.0

Answer (score 7):

You are confusing Gradle with the Android **gradle plugin**, which generally matches the version of Android Studio.  The latest version (at time of writing) is 2.2.2.  It is generally set in your project's base build.gradle as you have shown above.

The Gradle wrapper is what you're looking for.  You can change the wrapper's settings in your project's `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file.

Change

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.1-all.zip
```

Again, this is separate from the Android gradle plugin, which simply marries Gradle with Android Studio.

[Find all distributions here](http://services.gradle.org/distributions/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Gradle Version Compatibility for Android Studio

[Gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lw819.png)

refer to [link](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility)

Comment: Thansk I'll try this

Answer (score 1):

A problem occurred research project ': sample'.

Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application'] 
Minimum supported Gradle version is 3.3. Current version is 3.2.1.
The current gradle configuration is also changed to 3.3. The project is running without problems, but can not use the command line (gradle and ./gradlew). 
Refer to the online program: 
1. Modify gradle-wrapper.properties, and Invalidate Caches / Restart ..., or do not work.
Later in the gradle forum to find a program: Thank you Henry 
As new release with the fix not available yet, the former walk-around works fine.

```
Buildscript { 
System.properties ['com.android.build.gradle.overrideVersionCheck'] = 'true' 
... 
}
```

. So mark what.

> Correction statement : I later found that I installed the sdkman tool,
>   the tool installed 3.2.1 version, and this should be related (⊙ o ⊙)!
>   .  At the beginning of the show gradle version, will show 3.2.1
>   version (I am still very depressed, change or show 3.2.1), I have
>   changed to the environment variable 3.3. I set the gradle environment
>   variable first, the following is set sdkman environment variable (this
>   order may also affect). So the final reason is still installed 3.2.1
>   version.